# Minimum elements in a set of measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, optimization

I am considering the following form of optimization w.r.t. the measure $\mu$:

$$
\inf_{\mu\in\mathfrak{M}}\int fd\mu
$$

where $\mathfrak{M}$ is a set of measures; for example, the set of probability measures in a measurable space.

Could you tell me the condition where the minimum of the above exists.

Of course, I know that the compactness is the key in finite dimensional spaces; however, how about such infinite dimensional spaces?

I have studied finite dimensional analysis, but I am not familiar with functional analysis and Lebesgue measure theory.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please give more information on the function $f$ and the spaces involved?

Comment: Compactness is always the key ;)

Comment: @Mike The function $f\colon\Bbb{R}^n\times T\to \Bbb{R}$ is measurable, proper concave. $T$ is a support of any measures $\mu$ in $\mathfrak{M}$. I should have wrote more detailed from that $\int_T f(x,t) d\mu(t)$.